# slam package install fails with make error

Tags: r, linker

I'm trying to install the slam package, but it seems to fail on my system. I'm running ubuntu 12.04. I thought it was a missing library or something so I installed a few that match liblas, but no dice.

```
* installing *source* package ‘slam’ ...
** package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c grouped.c -o grouped.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c sparse.c -o sparse.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c util.c -o util.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -o slam.so grouped.o sparse.o util.o -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [slam.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘slam’
* removing ‘/home/brandon/.R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/slam’
```

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install liblas1 liblas-bin liblas-dev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have something fishy going on with your system.  Try to follow `/usr/lib/libblas.*` which on my Ubuntu 12.04 server, with the OpenBLAS package installed, yields:

```
edd@max:~$ ls -log /usr/lib/libblas.* /etc/alternatives/libblas*                                                                                                                                                                 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 36 Jun 15 09:41 /etc/alternatives/libblas.a -> /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 37 Jun 15 09:41 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so -> /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 39 Jun 15 09:41 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf -> /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 27 May  9  2012 /usr/lib/libblas.a -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 28 May  9  2012 /usr/lib/libblas.so -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 32 May  9  2012 /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf
edd@max:~$
```

You should have something similar, albeit with the base blas you have installed.

Comment: libBlas not liblas. Thanks for that! I installed libblas-dev and it worked!

Comment: By the way, if you install `r-base-dev` this is automagically taken care of.  Which is why we created `r-base-dev` in the first place :)

Comment: I confused -lblas as liblas rather than libblas as it should have been. You pointed out, correctly, that it was libblas (not the other one).

Comment: Understood. And `r-base-dev`, which you really should have had installed, has a depends on that package (well, one of the different blas-dev packages) hence preventing the manual search.  Do install `r-base-dev` and see if it pulls anything else in for you.

Comment: Yes, it did. I guess I was missing a bunch of libs! Thanks

Comment: On Debian `r-base-dev` depends on `libblas-dev | libatlas-base-dev`, so it might as well happen, that it is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `libblas-dev` installed (here with the 'openblas' version), but the system cannot find the libs for some reason (although you already played around with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, adjusting it to something you found in `ls -log /usr/lib/libblas.* /etc/alternatives/libblas*`), the following workaround should do it:

- manually download the package you see in the output
- unpack the archive
- step into the new directory `slam`
- type `R CMD INSTALL .` to see the commands which get executed
- go into directory `src`
- copy and execute the commands manually, which you have seen before, except of the last one (where the `-lblas` parameter is in)
- copy the command, but change `-lblas` to `-lopenblas`, and execute
- this last command should now also succeed
- go back to directory slam with `cd ..`
- execute again `R CMD INSTALL .`
- because everything is already compiled, this step does not need get repeated, only the rest of the installation will run (and succeed, if the command line with now `-lopenblas` succeeded)