# Failure to install slam package

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [slam package install fails with make error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532682/slam-package-install-fails-with-make-error)

I get this error when I attempt to install the package `slam` (I am using RStudio menu)

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [slam.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘slam’
```

I have to apoloigize for stating that I am using Xubuntu 12.04 x64 with RStudio 0.97.173.

Comment: Yes of course, I am using Xubuntu 12.04 x64 with R 2.15.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MacOS or Windoze you need to install the tools in order to compile source packages. (Although we could ask why you are not installing the binaries?) The Mac tools are obtained from the installation discs or from the Xcode resources. See this page for more resources and information on Mac tools: http://r.research.att.com/tools/  For Windoze go here: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ If you are on Linux, the libraries and compilers should be part of your installation.